# Repository class

Tags: c#, oop

I have a UserRepository Class, few of responsibilities it has are,

1 - Query ADUser from ActiveDirectory using few disposable classes

2 - Convert this ADUser Object to my Business Object as I don't want to keep using "using" in my main code.

How can i efficiently handle disposable objects in my repository class, e.g. I am using PrincipalContext, UserPrincipalExtension, PrincipalSearcher etc.. they are all disposable..

**Problem**

I don't want to add "using" to each method (like 20 methods) in my repo class,

```
public static List<MyUser> GetUsersInOU(string ouPath)
{
    List<MyUser> users = new List<MyUser>();

    using (PrincipalContext pc = MyUtilities.GetPrincipalContext(ouPath))
    using (UserPrincipalExtension user = new UserPrincipalExtension(pc))
    using (PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(user))
    {
        user.Enabled = true;
        foreach (UserPrincipalExtension u in ps.FindAll())
        {
            users.Add(MyUser.Load(u.SamAccountName));
        }
    }

    return users;
}
```

**Edit - bit out of context**

I found this solution but it is using DirectoryEntry I want to extend it by using PrincipalContext but not able to do so :(

http://landpyactivedirectory.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Landpy.ActiveDirectory/Landpy.ActiveDirectory/Core/DirectoryEntryRepository.cs

Comment: Is there any reason why you don´t want any `using` in your main-app? Furthermore I cannot see your actual problem nor your actual question as its quite unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Why should you add the provided code to all your DTO-classes? However you should consider to CALL that method within the 20 methods.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I was trying to think by OOP (am noob in this field), can't I have static instances or something, and they get disposed automatically or using destructors, I am just not exactly sure

Comment: @HimBromBeere maybe I need another layer in my project ?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `GetUsersInOU(string ouPath)` whereever you want you work with list of users. I assume that `MyUser` class is not `IDisposable` so you do not have to worry about `using` statements outside of `GetUsersInMyOU` - `PrincipalContext, UserPrincipalExtension, PrincipalSearcher` objects get correctly created and disposed within calling `GetUsersInMyOU`.

EDIT (after @PleaseTeach's comment):

You can have `IUserRepository`:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    List<MyUser> GetUsersInOU(string ouPath);   
}
```

Then implement `IUserRepository` in your `UserRepository` class:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository, IDisposable
{
    private PrincipalContext _pc;
    private UserPrincipalExtension _user;
    private PrincipalSearcher _ps;

    public UserRepository()
    {
        _pc = MyUtilities.GetPrincipalContext(ouPath);
        _user = new UserPrincipalExtension(pc);
        _ps = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
    }

    public List<MyUser> GetUsersInOU(string ouPath)
    {
        List<MyUser> users = new List<MyUser>();

        user.Enabled = true;
        foreach (UserPrincipalExtension u in _ps.FindAll())
        {
            users.Add(MyUser.Load(u.SamAccountName));
        }

        return users;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       _ps.Dispose();
       _user.Dispose();
       _pc.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Using this approach, you can create all your `IDisposable` objects in constructor, use them in all methods within your class (no need to wrap their usage in `using` statements) and dispose them in `Dispose()` method.

Now you can call your method like this:

```
using(IUserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository())
{
    IList<MyUser> users = userRepo.GetUsersInOU("someOuPath");
}
```

Comment: I already understand that method is perfectly fine in sense of resource management, this is more like a modeling question not resource manamgent, thanks for reponse